# What does 五月雨式 means in this sentence?

Tags: words, business-japanese

> raj-san 五月雨式で申し訳ないのですが、緒方さんに実装のご説明をどこかでしていただくお願いを連絡しようと思います。取り急ぎご報告まで、

I understood that a guy is asking for some explanation of coding, but I couldn't understand what does **五月雨式** mean here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[五月雨]{さみだれ}式ですみません (or more infrequently 五月雨式にすみません) is a fixed expression. Indeed, you can have 申し訳ありません as in your email to make it more polite.

You can understand, 五月雨式で申し訳ありません as "sorry to bother you again". He might have sent you a lot of e-mails recently and he is apologizing for "spamming" you.

五月雨式に means "like the ceaseless pourings of May".

All in all, your sentence means:

> Sorry to bother you again but, I am thinking about contacting 緒方さん to ask for some explanations about the implementation. Sorry for the brevity but you know what I will do.

I had a long hesitation whether [緒方]{おがた}さんに binds to 連絡 or していただく I assumed it was 連絡.

Answer (score 1):

さみだれしきに【五月雨式に】: intermittently; off and on

http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/edc/16001990401/meaning/m0u/%E4%BA%94%E6%9C%88%E9%9B%A8%E5%BC%8F/